# Keep ampersand character codes in HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the labels:

```
var labels = ['Hello user&#44; start here', 'E&amp;Y']; //etc
```

Labels are being concatenated in HTML like:

```
'<p>'+label[i]+'</p>'
```

So the effect is:

```
<p>Hello user, start here</p>
```

and browser shows text `'Hello user, start here'`. It is a good behaviour, but I want to show labels also in another case as follows:

```
<p>Hello user&#44; start here</p>
```

so

`'Hello user&#44; start here'` without decoding.

How to get the desired effect?

EDIT:

I simplified this process to show us clearly what I meant:

```
var labels = ['Hello user&#44; start here', 'E&amp;Y'];
var label = $( "<p>"+labels[0]+"</p>");
$("body").append(label);
```

I can't modify the labels array.

Comment: this is unclear, can you expand on the desired process/outcome, and how it doesn't work now?

Comment: You could change the first value of the labels list to be &amp;&#35;44&#59; so that when it interprets the html code it shows up exactly how you want it after being interpreted. There is probably a cleaner answer, but this is a possibility.

Comment: I assume you're using `.innerHTML = ...` right now? What you need is to add the `<p>` first, then use its `.textContent` instead. That will keep all characters as opposed to parsing them as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the text directly into a text node it won't be decoded: `document.createTextNode(labels[0])`

```js
var labels = ['Hello user&#44; start here', 'E&amp;Y'];

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  '<p>'+labels[0]+'</p>'
);

document.body.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(labels[0])
);
```

jquery:

```js
var labels = ['Hello user&#44; start here', 'E&amp;Y'];

$("body").append(
  '<p>'+labels[0]+'</p>'
);

$("body").append(
  $("<p>").text(labels[0])
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anybody know how to this in JQuery referring to my first post?

Comment: @scartout I've added an example how to do it with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

do you try with ... safe html code...    `&amp;` is showed as "&"

```
var labels = ['Hello user&amp;#44; start here', 'E&amp;Y'];
```